# Auto mapper issue with Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

Hi all I do have an issue with my auto mapping objects in my case I need properties to be skipped over and map the db context properties with my custom object

here is how I'm trying to convert the object but i am getting an error
***System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object***

```
var library = await Task.FromResult(mapper.Map<test.WebApi.Dto.Library>(item));
```

here is my custom mapper class

```
  public class CustomMapper: Profile
  {
    public CustomMapper()
    {
        
        CreateMap<test.WebApi.Models.Library, test.WebApi.Dto.Library>().ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.Ignore());
    }
  }
```

here are my dto class and the dbcontext classes

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

#nullable disable

namespace test.WebApi.Models
{
    public partial class Library
    {
        public Library()
        {
            GeneratedFiles = new HashSet<GeneratedFile>();
            Templates = new HashSet<Template>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public long? TenantId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<GeneratedFile> GeneratedFiles { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Template> Templates { get; set; }
    }
}


using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test.WebApi.Dto
{
    public class Library
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public long TenantId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }        
    }
}
```

packages and info

AutoMapper 10.1.1
AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection 8.1.1

.net core 5.0

Comment: So, what should `TenantId` be mapped into if it's null?

Comment: 1. Which Library is the dto? 2. Please share the Library models with namespace. 3. How do you get the `item`? 4. What is your version of asp.net core and automapper nuget package?

Comment: I have updated the namespace and package details

Comment: Hi @Thili, could you please share how do you DI the mapper, I tried set `item` to null but it still works. But when I DI the mapper in a wrong way, it appears the error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a whole working demo:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMapper mapper;
    public HomeController(IMapper mapper)
    {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }
    public void Index()
    {
        var item = new test.WebApi.Models.Library()
        {
            Description = "aa"
        };
        var library = await Task.FromResult(mapper.Map<test.WebApi.Dto.Library>(item));
    }   
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(CustomMapper));
```